# Uninstall all spying updates in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, spyware, anti-spyware

[This page](https://www.hackread.com/microsoft-updates-spy-on-windows7-8-users/) recommends to stay away from the following updates:

```
KB2876229 # SKYPE, If you want Skype then install it.
KB2923545 # RDP
KB2970228
KB3035583
KB2990214
KB3021917
KB3068708 # Telemetry
KB2592687
KB2660075
KB2506928
KB2952664 # x2
KB3050265
KB2726535
KB2994023
KB3022345 # Replaced by KB3068708 Telemetry
KB3022345 # Caused false sfc result
KB2545698 # (IE9)
KB3065987
```

How do I uninstall all those updates, and prevent WindowsUpdate from reinstalling them?

Or is there a Software, that does all this for me?

Comment: If it is possible entirely depends if you have used Disk Cleanup or not, normally, you just uninstall the update.

Comment: The article you linked to has step by step instructions on how to uninstall them, what did you not understand in the ***"How To Remove/Uninstall Snooping Windows Updates"*** section of the article? Also, I would not trust that website if it considers updating RDP to 8.1 "Spyware" (KB2923545), I can not think how it could be considered spyware and if they think that is spyware when it is not what else do they have wrong (or more importantly what updates could they have missed!)

Comment: It seems quite a lot of work to uninstall each one of them one-by-one. Can you provide a batch script that does the whole thing in one go?

Comment: What is stopping you from writing a batch script yourself, its just taking the list you already posted here and putting `wusa /uninstall /kb:` before each line (minus the KB and the comments)

Comment: @rubo77 - You asked how to uninstall them.  You simply uninstall them using Add/Remove Programs, provided you have not performed the cleanup routine.  If you have then your only option is to install Windows 8.1 again.  The FUD in the article is high, higher then the force in Luke, so much FUD.

Comment: I added an answer that works, but it is not really elegant, because you have to click for each single update, I hope, someone can provide a more elegant solution

Comment: @Ramhound this is not FUD, it is fact that Windows operating systems spy on you, this may have only been a rumor for all operating systems up until 10, but after 10's announcement and release, windows 10 is confirmed (by microsoft) to have features that spy on you which can never be disabled, and the ones that can be disabled but are enabled by default are too damn many to count. And many of these features were secretly added to Windows 7 and 8 through update after Windows 10's announcement and more after it's release. Please get informed, starting with this: https://i.imgur.com/iHge6RJ.jpg

Comment: @Ramhound and for some more, this: http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/11/02/microsoft-confirms-unstoppable-windows-10-tracking/#2c1c55f92f4a and this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/servicesagreement/ (Actually read it, in particular article "2.b" and roll it around in your head for a moment to fully understand what it means, this applies to all microsoft products, it's their general service agreement, it's ugly) And you know, there's just something fishy about how eager Microsoft are to FORCE Windows 10 on users who do not want it and are sticking with 7 and 8. Pentagon is in on it.

Comment: I already read that section numerous times.  I read it entirely different.  I still think it's there is nothing to the claims.  That particular section of the agreement does not apply to Windows

Comment: You won't convince me of anything if you use WiFi sense as evidence a feature that had been miss reported by pretty much everyone

Comment: @Ramhound Not misreported... Dude, my point was that microsoft are spying on you openly, they're not even hiding it, not even trying to hide it. And wifi sense is just a terrible thing to have enabled by default seeing as it's a gaping security hole. And it might not apply directly to Windows as you say after all, but it applies to Cortana and Windows Live Accounts, which are core elements of Windows 10, and thus it is free for interpretation whether or not this applies to the entirety of Windows 10, but I guess for 7 and 8 and XP they're clear of this.

Comment: iOS devices share your access points between your devices.  I don't see a different between that functionality and WiFi Sense.  WiFi Sense only functions if you have use social media websites.  You also have to specifically enable sharing each social network.  You can also opt out of WiFi Sense something you can't do on Android or iOS with those platforms similar features.  WiFi Sense does not share the password to your access point, so its not clear, why its terrible.  Its not "free" to interpretation, that segment, does not apply to Windows.  I still believe its being misreported.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool on https://github.com/WindowsLies/BlockWindows that you can use to deaktivate all spying updates.

Just download it into your standard Windows `Download` Folder and run it with right-click as administrator.

It is important to store it in the standard `Download` Folder because the script relies on that

Comment: I would rather use the Aegis Voat script  mentioned in my answer, BlockWindows is outdated in comparison, and clearly not as well maintained. But well, back in august 2015 this might have been a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best current way to do this is using an advanced batch script known as [Aegis Voat](https://voat.co/v/technology/comments/853510) ([Github link](https://github.com/th3power/aegis-voat))([Direct Download Link for V 1.13](https://github.com/th3power/aegis-voat/archive/v1.13.zip)) which does this for Windows 7 and Windows 8, and does it very well. That page also provides a list of updates you should stay away from, the script also removes a few annoyances such as the new forced Windows 10 upgrade download as well as a few windows services that you probably don't want.

You can alternatively do this by hand in the windows update program, uninstalling and hiding each update you don't want one by one.

This is the current list of updates (february 21, 2016):

```
kb update   description
kb971033    update for windows activation technologies
kb2882822   update for adding itracerelogger interface support
kb2902907   description not available, update was pulled by microsoft
kb2922324   description not available, update was pulled by microsoft
kb2952664   update for upgrading windows 7
kb2976978   update for windows 8.1 and windows 8
kb2977759   update for windows 7 rtm
kb2990214   update that enables you to upgrade from windows 7 to a later version of windows
kb3012973   upgrade to windows 10
kb3014460   update for windows insider preview / upgrade to windows 10
kb3015249   update that adds telemetry points to consent.exe in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7
kb3021917   update for windows 7 sp1 for performance improvements
kb3022345   update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry
kb3035583   update installs get windows 10 app in windows 8.1 and windows 7 sp1
kb3042058   update for cipher suite priority order (contains winlogon spying elements)
kb3044374   update that enables you to upgrade from windows 8.1 to windows 10
kb3046480   update for migrating .net when upgrading to later version of windows
kb3050265   update for windows update client for windows 7 june 2015
kb3050267   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 june 2015
kb3064683   update for windows 8.1 oobe modifications to reserve windows 10
kb3065987   update for windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 july 2015
kb3065988   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2 july 2015
kb3068708   update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry
kb3072318   update for windows 8.1 oobe modifications to reserve windows 10
kb3074677   compatibility update for upgrading to windows 10
kb3075249   update that adds telemetry points to consent.exe in windows 8.1 and windows 7
kb3075851   update for windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 august 2015
kb3075853   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2 august 2015
kb3080149   update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry
kb3081437   august 18, 2015, compatibility update for upgrading to windows 10
kb3081454   september 8, 2015, compatibility update for upgrading to windows 10
kb3081954   update for work folders improvements in windows 7 sp1 (contains telemetry elements)
kb3083324   update for windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 september 2015
kb3083325   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2 september 2015
kb3083710   update for windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 october 2015
kb3083711   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2 october 2015
kb3086255   september 8, 2015, security update for the graphics component in windows (breaks safedisc)
kb3088195   october 13, 2015, security update for windows kernel (reported to contain a keylogger)
kb3090045   windows update for reserved devices in windows 8.1 or windows 7 sp1 (windows 10 upgrade elements)
kb3093983   security update for internet explorer: october 13, 2015 (ie spying elements)
kb3102810   windows 10 upgrade elements
kb3102812   windows 10 upgrade elements
kb3112343   update for windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2 december 2015
kb3112336   update for windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2 december 2015
kb3123862   updated capabilities to upgrade windows 8.1 and windows 7
kb3135445   windows update client for windows 7 and windows server 2008 r2: february 2016
kb3135449   windows update client for windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 r2: february 2016
```

Installation guide is well.. download the zip file, extract it into a folder of your choosing, and then run aegis.cmd as administrator.

Answer (score -2):

create a file `win8SpyUdateUninstall.bat`

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:2923545
wusa /uninstall /kb:2970228
wusa /uninstall /kb:3035583
wusa /uninstall /kb:2990214
wusa /uninstall /kb:3021917
wusa /uninstall /kb:3068708
wusa /uninstall /kb:2592687
wusa /uninstall /kb:2660075
wusa /uninstall /kb:2506928
wusa /uninstall /kb:2952664
wusa /uninstall /kb:3050265
wusa /uninstall /kb:2726535
wusa /uninstall /kb:2994023
wusa /uninstall /kb:3022345
wusa /uninstall /kb:3022345
wusa /uninstall /kb:2545698
wusa /uninstall /kb:3065987
```

open a `cmd` and call the script.

You will get a popup fo reach update, either saying that it is not installed anyway or asking you to uninstall. after each uninstall you can press "restart later" to finish the whole script before restartint windows.

### TODO:

- prevent windows from suggesting those updates on the next update-check
- install a daemon, that checks for new spyware updates to arrive in the future